# [Android]This app won't run unless you update google play services

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-services

I implemented a google account sign in button for my app, when I open the app (Android 6.0.1) and enter the sign in page, it shows a dialog saying **This app won't run unless you update google play services**

This is my code:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

I checked the google play services on my android device is 8.1.86
**Is that because 8.1<9.2?**
How to avoid this message for my users who has outdated google play services app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check Google Play Services you can use [int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) method:

```
    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
        .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
```

If the resultCode = [SUCCESS](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#SUCCESS) then everything is fine. Otherwise, you decide what to do, if [SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) you could ask if the user wants to update or you might have other login options.

If you what to show the original dialog call [boolean showErrorDialogFragment (Activity activity, int errorCode, int requestCode)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#showErrorDialogFragment(android.app.Activity,%20int,%20int)).